# Appending a list which was created with ToExpression

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to create many different lists by changing one part of the list name with a variable defined as a string, then creating a name for that list using ToExpression[].

```
x="halfOm";

Evaluate[ToExpression["exlist" <> x]] = {};
```

Here, it outputs what I want. I now have an empty list with the name exlisthalfOm.

```
Append[ToExpression["exlist" <> x], 1]
```

Here I have created the list $\{1\}$. But now, I want to redefine the list from above, exlisthalfOm, as this new list. Every attempt I have made gives me some kind of Tag error.

I do not want to write

```
exlisthalfOm = Append[ToExpression["exlist" <> x], 1]
```

because I want the left side to change when I change $x$.

I think the root of the problem is that when I try

```
Evaluate[ToExpression["exlist" <> x]] = Append[ToExpression["exlist" <> x], 1]
```

Evaluate[ToExpression["exlist" <> x]] evaluates to {} when I want it to evaluate to exlisthalfOm

Comment: Your expressions don't work after you assign a value for x because that value is substituted into your expressions before they are evaluated. You are trying to do `ToExpression["exlist" <> {1}]`, which fails. If I'm honest, none of this sounds like a good idea. Typically generating symbol names is prone to this kind of problems. Can you use functions to extract your list instead? Define something like an `exlistgenerator` that you then apply to your list and it gives you the portion of the list you want?

Comment: I am not attempting to concatenate "exlist" with {1}. I had an incorrect ToString around the x which I have fixed now. Maybe that's where the confusion came from.

Comment: In the last line, I just need Evaluate[ToExpression["exlist" <> x]] to evaluate to exlisthalfOm again, instead of {}. Is there no way to do this with Hold or some type of function like that?

Comment: I am not sure that what you want to do could be done in a straightforward manner. Perhaps you could give us the context in which your need arises, to see if maybe a completely different approach would work?